# Does the system status check and upgrade version check only list available updates for in-app extensions?

Tags: extension

It seems like extensions which are listed in the extension directory but not available for in-app distribution are not included in update checks. They also don't appear in the sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/cache/extensions.json file which seems to be the list of available updates it retrieves. I've run the version update job and "refresh" button on the extensions page manually and can see it downloads a new one.

So for example on the status page it says all extensions are up to date but I know they are not.

Is this a local config issue or is this just how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I discovered what you can do is put this in civicrm.settings.php:

`$civicrm_setting['domain']['ext_repo_url'] = 'https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver={ver}|cms={uf}|ready=';`

Note the `ready=` at the end (the [default](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/597c41c5868824754795a31d2ffb11bc6aae96e0/settings/Extension.setting.php#L32) is without it).

This then properly shows you pending upgrades for your installed extensions that are in the extension directory but not approved for automatic distribution. The downside is it now lists all the available extensions for your civi version on the Add New tab on the Extensions page as if they were approved for automatic distribution.

An alternative is I've made an extension that adds a status check to show you available updates for your extensions that are not automatically distributed: https://civicrm.org/extensions/notify-about-upgrades-unapproved-extensions